# How do we install gcc-go to AIX machine power-pc-7 bigendian 64 bit?

Tags: go, gcc, gnu, aix

I have a AIX machine which runs on power-pc-7 bigendian 64 bit I understand installing Go compiler is easy for Windows,Linux and Mac but if we want to install it on AIX then it involves different steps.

I downloaded the tar file supported for my AIX machine "go1.14.1.linux-pcc64le.tar.gz" using the link "https://dl.google.com/go/go.1.14.1.linux-pcc64le.tar.gz" after downloading this not sure how to proceed also I am using the littleendian one as I didn't any reference for bigendian .

All I wanted to do first before i start my project is to run a hello world Go program on my AIX machine does anyone have any idea on this ?

Answer (score 0):

A little-endian program will *not* work on a big-endian operating system and vice-versa.

Two alternatives:

1. Download `golang` from http://www.bullfreeware.com/?searching=true&package=golang&from=&to=&libraries=false&exact=false&version=5 but they only have go v1.14 and it only works on AIX 7.2.
2. Download the source and follow the instructions on https://golang.org/doc/install/source -- it's not trivial as go is written in go nowadays, so you need to install go 1.4 first.